# Error when running flask app - function not defined when I make a call to the python script

Tags: python, flask, undefined, werkzeug

Im trying to get what is essentially a spell checking tool to work. When I run locally the html appears fine in browser but when I enter data to be passed into the python script I get error: spell() not defined, even though it is and the python part works fine. I'm new to Flask apps hopefully someone can help thx

````
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import string
import json


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/result", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    inp = request.form.to_dict()
    text = inp['text']
    s = spell(text)
    return render_template("index.html", text=text, suggs=s)  
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)


def spell(s):
    copy = s
    with open('english3.txt') as fh:
        l = []
        for line in fh:
            line = line.rstrip()
            l.append(line) ```
... below is just the rest of the python script

[error i get when running: html appears fine in browser but when I enter data to be passed into the python script i get this error.][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCB3y.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the `spell()` function at the beginning of your script before calling it:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import string
import json

def spell(s):
    copy = s
    with open('english3.txt') as fh:
        l = []
        for line in fh:
            line = line.rstrip()
            l.append(line)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/result", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    inp = request.form.to_dict()
    text = inp['text']
    s = spell(text)
    return render_template("index.html", text=text, suggs=s)  
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

Comment: unfortunately did not work